# JAVA_HOME error when using cordova

Tags: java, linux, cordova, ionic-framework

hey i am trying to run `cordova run android` and got this error :

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/ronin/Android
JAVA_HOME=/home/ronin/jdk1.8.0_161/
(node:7717) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
    at /home/ronin/Downloads/SyncApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:367:19
    at _fulfilled (/home/ronin/Downloads/SyncApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
```

clearly my `JAVA_HOME` variable is correctly set ( i get the same error without `/` in the end);
i am running Arch Linux and i know it uses, bu default, the `openjdk` versions. is that the source of the error cause this is what i get when i run `java -version`

```
openjdk version "9.0.4"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

help !

Comment: Oracle JDK installed on system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to uninstall OpenJDK 9.x.x and install [Java SE Development Kit 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) for build ionic app in android or ios and then set [JAVA_HOME](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/platforms/android/#setting-environment-variables) path.